# html index from several directories in python

Tags: python-2.7

my question comes from a problem that I have.

I have several index.html files stored in different directories, and that I would like to have or generate in python is a script that gathers in one html file all the html files stored in the directories. I don't want to change in every directory and open the html file several times I just want to follow the html files from a general html file.

Any help or ideas?
Thanks

Comment: ```os.system("cat `find -iname '*.html'` > out.html")
```?

Comment: thanks theVOID, actually I have the route for all those html files, my idea is to generate some kind of html file that can include the others, I mean I want to store the html file in my home and then display the others html files from directories directly from my new html file stored in my home
.